# create a database MonetDB

Tags: database, monetdb

I have a problem with the creation of a new database. 
After that I started MonetDB Server, I insert this command: 
mserver5 --dbpath="C:\database1"

But the server give me this error:
!SintaxException:parseError:mserver5 --dbpath="C:\database1"
!SintaxException:parseError: ^';' expected

What should i do to resolve this problem? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What MonetDB version are you using on what platform?
Presumably Windows and this error message is indicative of a broken installation, potentially caused by moving files/folders around directly on your machine, such that the expected location for server initialisation files can not be found.